# Detect URL changes in JavaFX webview

Tags: java, javafx

I'm making a simple JavaFX app embedding a WebView. After searching a lot on the internet, I still can't find any solution to detect URL changes while the user is navigating the web.

Is there any method such as the actionPerfomed() method, but for URL changes? Or is there any other way to do it?

Thank you

Comment: I take it your "searching a lot on the internet" didn't actually take in the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say `webEngine` is the engine of your WebView. You can detect the URL changes inside the following `changed(...)` method:

```
webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State>() {
     @Override
     public void changed(ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState) {

           if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                 System.out.println(webEngine.getLocation()); //NEW URL
           }

     }
});
```